# Generate a sample from parts of the data frame that were not sampled R

Tags: r, sample

I have a data frame that has over 8000 rows.
This is an example of what the data looks like:

```
structure(list(execid = structure(c(31181, 31181, 31181, 31195, 
31206, 31212, 31212, 31213, 31222, 31228, 31241, 31263, 31283, 
31283, 31306, 31306), label = "(firstnm) execid", format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    exec_fname = structure(c("Ellen", "Ellen", "Ellen", "Craig", 
    "Gregory", "David", "David", "Paul", "Kevin", "William", 
    "Brian", "Craig", "Jonathan", "Jonathan", "Mark", "Mark"), label = "(firstnm) exec_fname", format.stata = "%26s"), 
    coname_execucomp = structure(c("DU PONT (E I) DE NEMOURS", 
    "DU PONT (E I) DE NEMOURS", "DU PONT (E I) DE NEMOURS", "TCF FINANCIAL CORP", 
    "SPECTRA ENERGY CORP", "BANK MUTUAL CORP", "BANK MUTUAL CORP", 
    "DPL INC", "USANA HEALTH SCIENCES INC", "ATLAS AIR WORLDWIDE HLDG INC", 
    "GRAND CANYON EDUCATION INC", "RUTHS HOSPITALITY GROUP INC", 
    "IOMEGA CORP", "IOMEGA CORP", "FIRST SOLAR INC", "FIRST SOLAR INC"
    ), label = "(firstnm) coname_execucomp", format.stata = "%50s")), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've taken a random sample of 100 of the of the data using the `sample` function bellow:

```
sample<-exec_names[sample(nrow(exec_names), 100), ]
```

I'm wondering how can I take another sample of 100 from this data without it including what was included in the above sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `anti_join` function from the `dplyr` package:

```
sample2 <- exec_names %>%
  anti_join(sample1, by = c("execid", "exec_fname", "coname_execucomp")) %>%
  sample_n(100)
```

The `anti_join` function compares the specified columns `(execid, exec_fname, and coname_execucomp)` between the original data frame and the first sample, and removes the matching rows.

Comment: Thank you! I'm wondering how can I create the same sample again? because it doesn't look like the ```sample()``` function is able to recreate the same sample. This means that I cannot use the code you provided above to create something outside of my current sample, if that makes sense.

Comment: What do you mean by the _same sample_? You are taking first sample **randomly**, aren't you?

Comment: I see what you are saying. I exported the first sample, maybe the solution is to import it again and use your code instead of trying to re-generate that first random sample again! Thanks!

Comment: Let's say you already have first sample inside file `sampled_data.csv`. So, you can add `new_data <- read.csv("sampled_data.csv")` before the code provided in the post to make sure always have the same first sample:
```new_data <- read.csv("sampled_data.csv")
sample2 <- exec_names %>%
  anti_join(new_data, by = c("execid", "exec_fname", "coname_execucomp")) %>%
  sample_n(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I would make a dataframe of indexes that encompass the entire range of indexes. If you wanted, you could save that dataframe as a csv to be used later too.

```r
library(tidyverse)

#set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(14155)

#random data
exec_names = tibble(x = 1:1000, y = rnorm(1000))

#generate a sample index dataframe
random_samples <- tibble(row = rep(1:100, 10),
                         index = sample(1:1000, 1000)) |>
  mutate(group = cumsum(row_number() %% 100 == 0)+1) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, names_prefix = "sample_", values_from = index)

#sample 100 different samples 
exec_1 = exec_names[random_samples$sample_1,]
exec_2 = exec_names[random_samples$sample_2,]
exec_3 = exec_names[random_samples$sample_3,]
```

Or even easier (and only with base r), you could just sample all indices for the entire dataset at the beginning and then just sunset the vector of indices:

```r
#set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(14155)

#random data
exec_names = data.frame("x" = 1:1000, "y" = rnorm(1000))

#generate a sample index
random_samples <- sample(1:1000, 1000)

#sample 100 different samples 
exec_1 = exec_names[random_samples[1:100],]
exec_2 = exec_names[random_samples[100:200],]
exec_3 = exec_names[random_samples[200:300],]
```

Comment: What does it mean to generate sample indexes? and when you do a set.seed() does it mean that the same sample can later be reproduced? are these samples with or without replacement? Thank you!

Comment: Generate sample index is just sampling 1-the max sample index. So if you have 100 rows, you sample (without replacement) 1-100. `set.seed()` definitely makes it reproducible.